# View and Activity how to share data in android.content.Context?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-context

I want `MyView` can share data with `MyActivity`, so I need they can put data into `Context` and get data from `Context`, How to do that?

```
class MyView extends Button {

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        put data into context ...

        get data from context ... 
    }

}

class MyActivity extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.xxx);

         put data into context ...

         get data from context ... 
     } 
}
```

I know `Activity` is a instance of `Context`, and there is `Context` in the `View`'s construtor.So I think when the `Activity` started, At sometime, `View` is trigger by event, so `View` put some data in `Context`, then at sometime, `Activity` is trigger by event, so it cant get data from 'Context'. I want `Context` to be a `email box` which both `View` and `Activity` send and get emails from it. I think there is some methods like `put(key, val)` and `get(key)` in `Context` but I not found.

Comment: You cant. You should do it with accessors and callbacks.

Comment: You should ask more clearly about the scenario you want, since there are many solutions available

Comment: If you only want to exchange data you could create a MyView Object in your MyActivity class. Then the MyActivity class can put itself or just the data you want to exchange in the constructor or other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@malrok44 's idea is inspired me. This is my solution.

```
interface Interacton {
      void putData(key, val)
      object getData(key)
}

class MyActivity extends Activity implements Interacton {

     public void oncreate() {
           getData(xx) 
           putData(xx,yy) 
     }

     private Map map = new HashMap  

     public void putData(key, val) {
          map.put(key, val);
     }

     public object getData(key) {
          return map.get(key)
     }
}

class MyView extends Button {

     public MyView(Context context) {
         Interaction ctx = (Interaction)context;
         ctx.put(xx,yy)
         ctx.get(xx)
     }
}
```

I think `ThreadLocal` is be ok, but I am not sure it is safe?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the context by invoking `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, or this when call it in the activity class.